# Remove Duplicate Object In List Java

Tags: java, list

I have class:

```
class MyClass {
    String s1;
    String s2;
}
```

List Object include

> [{s1: "a", s2: "b"}, {s1: "a", s2: "c"}, {s1: "a", s2: "b"}, {s1: "a",
>   s2: "d"}]

I want to remove object duplicate 2 properties s1 and s2

Expect Result:

> [{s1: "a", s2: "b"}, {s1: "a", s2: "c"}, {s1: "a", s2: "d"}]

If can use Java 8 is better

Help me :(

Comment: If you had a list of some object with a well defined `equals` and `hashcode` methods, then to remove duplicates all you would need to do would be to add your list to a set.  So, I vote for creating a list of actual objects, not just strings.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Your question as it stands is too broad and doesn't show any working. This means your question will be down-voted and/or closed. Have a look at [how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and improve your question accordingly.

Comment: @user:7665222, You must need to implement equals and hash code contract in the respective class to address unique identification of the instance. Then if you don't have any concern with the collection type either `List` or `Set` then the baby step to collect unique/identical instances is to use `Set<MyClass>` other wise you can use `distinct()` function of stream api like `List<MyClass> identical = duplicates.stream().distinct().collect(Collectors.toList());`

Answer (score 1):

First override the `equals` and `hashCode` methods in your `MyClass` like so,

```
@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return 31 * s1.hashCode() + s2.hashCode();
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    return obj instanceof MyClass && ((MyClass) obj).getS1().equals(getS1())
            && ((MyClass) obj).getS2().equals(getS2());
}
```

Then the easiest way to eliminate duplicates would be using a `Set`.

`new HashSet<>(instances)`

Answer (score 0):

Use like this.

```
   List<MyClass> listWithoutDuplicates = listWithDuplicates.stream().distinct()
     .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

before using above you need to override equals method in your class

```
    class MyClass {
    String s1;
    String s2;
    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return 31 * s1.hashCode() + s2.hashCode();
    }
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {

     if(obj instanceof MyClass && ((MyClass) 
        obj).s1.equals(s1)
        && ((MyClass) obj).s2.equals(s2))
       return true;

     return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to override equal and hash code function  and then use the distinct function of Streaming API of java 8.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class MyClass {

  private String s1;
  private String s2;

  public MyClass() {
  }

  public MyClass(String s1, String s2) {
    this.s1 = s1;
    this.s2 = s2;
  }

  public String getS1() {
    return s1;
  }

  public MyClass setS1(String s1) {
    this.s1 = s1;
    return this;
  }

  public String getS2() {
    return s2;
  }

  public MyClass setS2(String s2) {
    this.s2 = s2;
    return this;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o) {
      return true;
    }
    if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) {
      return false;
    }
    MyClass myClass = (MyClass) o;
    return Objects.equals(getS1(), myClass.getS1()) &&
        Objects.equals(getS2(), myClass.getS2());
  }

  @Override
  public int hashCode() {
    return Objects.hash(getS1(), getS2());
  }

  @Override
  public String toString() {
    return "MyClass{" + "s1='" + s1 + '\'' + ", s2='" + s2 + '\'' + '}';
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<MyClass> list = new ArrayList<>();
    list.add(new MyClass("a", "b"));
    list.add(new MyClass("a", "c"));
    list.add(new MyClass("a", "b"));
    list.add(new MyClass("a", "d"));
    System.out.println("Original size is : " + list.size()); // Size is 4
    list.forEach(System.out::println);
    //Now remove duplicate
    List<MyClass> expected = list.stream().distinct().collect(Collectors.toList());
    System.out.println(
        "After remove duplication size is : " + expected.size()); // Here is your expected result size is 3
    expected.forEach(System.out::println);
  }
}
```

Here is the output :

Original size is : 4

MyClass{s1='a', s2='b'}

MyClass{s1='a', s2='c'}

MyClass{s1='a', s2='b'}

MyClass{s1='a', s2='d'}

After remove duplication size is : 3

MyClass{s1='a', s2='b'}

MyClass{s1='a', s2='c'}

MyClass{s1='a', s2='d'}

Answer (score 0):

It's not a must to implement hashcode() or equals(). Here's one way to do that:

```
Map<List<String>, MyClass> map = new HashMap<>();
List<MyClass> distinctList = myCollection.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(c -> Arrays.asList(c.s1, c.s2), Function.identity(), (x,y)->x))
    .values()
    .stream()
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```